# How to convert php array to c# array?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, .net, arrays

I want to assign value of tax_id, found a solution in `php` but i want to implement in c#, Please have a look

this is php code,`'tax_id'=>array(array(6,0,array(13)))`
can anyone convert this code snippets in c#, thanks

Comment: in `array(6,0,array(13))`, [0] is an int, [1] is an int and [2] is an `Int[]` with [0] an int. In C# things are type, Either the element of this array are Int or Array of int but they can't be both. Is it a 3D array? Are 6 and 0 is this exemple an int[] with only one element?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wan't a 3D Jagged array:

```
var jagged3D= new int[][][]
{
    new  int[][]{
         new int[]{6},
         new int[]{0},
         new int[]{13}
     }
};
```

Or a 2DJagged of a custom object

```
var jaggedCustom = new Custom[][] {
    new Custom[]{
        new Custom{
            A =3,
            B =0,
            C = new int[]{13}
        }
    }
};
```

But all element of an array has the same type. You can learn more about Single-Dimensional Arrays, Multidimensional Arrays, Jagged Arrays  with Msdn [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays). Using the left panel to navigate.